# How to delete from binarytree data and upgrade descendents ? django-mptt

Tags: python, django, algorithm, binary-tree, django-mptt

im trying a same days to solve, but i cant image the algorithm for this.

for example have a binary tree.

```
#               [1]          
#       [2]              [3]
#   [4]    [5]       [6]    [7]
# [8][9][10][11]  [12][13][14][15]
```

im need to delete [3], and the logical upgrade of descendents is, [6] in espace of [3], and [7] on space of [6]...
[14] on space of [7]...
always on logical up and left movement.

im try to apply this conditions if can convert this tree to a list python data based on element deleted.

```
# if list[0].children == 0 :
#   element.delete
# if list[0].children == 1 :
#   list[0] go to element.position
# if list[0].children == 2 :
#   list[0] go to element.position
#   list[1] go to list[0].position
```

im try to using django-mptt but i cant solve o im hang on this.

Comment: Hello Paul, im see that "Deleting a node with two children" return un result that is not the wanted predecessor.

Comment: Sry, I misread the question. My bad. I've retracted the vote.

Comment: Thanks, this example have other priority, like is most important ascendente then left side and then right side.

Comment: try showing us all the code you're working with, not just a section of it. describe what you expected to see and what you're seeing instead.